# Why is htaccess ignoring my first rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^myfile\.php$ redirector\.php?og_path=new_file_1[L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^myfile\.php$ redirector\.php?og_path=new_file_2[L,NC,QSA]
```

I have my htaccess set up with a simple rewrite rule similar to above. When I go to [www.mysite.com/myfile.php](http://www.mysite.com/myfile.php) the first redirector will be ignored and instead it will automatically go to the second (new_file_2). Every other rewrite rule works as expected.

Curiously though, it works fine on my localhost, but for some reason on my server it give me the error.

Comment: Well the RewriteConds must have been true then ...?

Comment: Does `/myfile.php` exist as a physical file or not? (Is the directory check really necessary?) Please explain in natural language what you are trying to do and why you expect the rules to behave in a particular way.